# Where are the 5 buffalo on the flip side of Whistlestop Rails?

Tags: yoshis-crafted-world

I have been tasked with finding 5 buffalo, but I have only found 4 and I am at the end of the level. Because of the trains in this level, I can't go back to look for the one I missed without doing the whole level over.

To save myself the time and energy of replaying this until I happen to spot it - where are the 5 buffalo in this level located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the locations of the Buffalos, copied the content over for posterity.

[image]

**Buffalo 1**: In the background just after the first care flower.

[image]

**Buffalo 2**: In the foreground to the left of the previous buffalo.

[image]

**Buffalo 3**: In the background at the very beginning of the first train ride.

[image]

**Buffalo 4**: In the background in a turn of the first train ride.

[image]

**Buffalo 5**: On the rocks in the background just after the position of the second Poochy Pups.

[Source](https://video-game-guide-walkthrough.supersoluce.com/solution/yoshis-crafted-world-guide-walkthrough/big-paper-peak/whistlestop-rails/)